# Automapper Exception. Unmapped members were found

Tags: automapper

I have the following inner exception being returned from automapper:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException was unhandled by user code
>
> HResult=-2146233088
>
> Message= Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members
>   below. add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver,
>   or modify the source/destination type
>
> CreateAndEditCustomer -> Customer (Destination member list)
>
> App.Web.Mvc.Models.Customer.CreateAndEditCustomer ->
>   App.Model.Customer (Destination member list)
>
> Deleted

Does anyone know what `Deleted` means?
How can I discover which members have not been mapped?

Comment: Do you have a property named `Deleted` on the destination object?

Comment: Hi Davin. Thanks for replying so quickly. My apologies, just found 'deleted' on the destination class. I thought this was a message returned by automapper. This is now resolved.